# Datetime picker inherits style from my table

Tags: eonasdan-datetimepicker

I'm using the datepicker from eonasdan (https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker)

It works great, but when I put it inside a table, it inherits the style of the table. It is as if the datepicker also becomes a table.

How can I avoid this?

I have the following in my CSS:

```
table.table {
    tr {
        th {
            color: #ff0000;  //red
        }
     }
  }
```

This is my html file:

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
      <th>Reconcile Date</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="pickdate">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Reconcile Date" class="form-control ">
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This sets the text in my table header to red. It *also* sets the days of the week and month name in my datepicker to red. Note the pickdate class load the datepicker

Comment: Could you post some code example? With CSS, it's always important to pay attention to which css file is linked first.

Comment: I tried to replicate in on JSFiddle, but for some reason I can't reproduce it there. I was hoping there was something obvious that I'm doing wrong. I'll post code shortly of what I have

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using Google Chrome's inspection tools I was able to find one of the classes on your datepicker table and add the CSS at that level. Here is the CSS and jsfiddle link:

```
 .table tr th{ color: red; }

 .table-condensed thead tr th{ color: black;}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/w8gmcgv4/5/

let me know if these work for you. Thanks!

Comment: Note that this rule will be applied to all tables with `.table-condensed` class (that is a [bootstrap class](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables-condensed)) and not only to picker section.

Answer (score 2):

You can add the following rule to your stylesheet to customize datetimepicker style:

```css
.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget {
  table {
    tr {
      th {
        color: black;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note that the picker has the [`debug`](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#debug) option that allows you inspect component's HTML to simplyfy style customization.

Working example:

```js
jQuery('#dates-ifbZ6A4b6r568bad40cd473').datetimepicker({
  format: "DD/MM/YYYY", debug: true
});
```

```css
table.table tr th {
  color: #ff0000;
}

.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget table tr th {
  color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.13.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <th>Debt Ref</th>
    <th>Reconcile Date</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>NOR087-DAN052</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Reconcile Date" name="dates[ifbZ6A4b6r568bad40cd473]" id="dates-ifbZ6A4b6r568bad40cd473" class="form-control ">
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<p>
 The text in the datepicker shouldn't be red
</p>
```