# Csslint in Visual Studio gives be an overqualified-elements warning

Tags: css, eonasdan-datetimepicker, csslint

I have the eonasdan datetime picker installed on my project. It works fine, but I had a problem when used in a table as the headings took on the colours of the table headings. Using an answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39378252/datetime-picker-inherits-style-from-my-table) question I used the following css to fix the problem

```css
div.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget table th {
    color: black;
    background-color: white;
}
```

It now looks like I think it should.

However, ever since I used it, I have been getting the warning

```
overqualified-elements  (CssLint) Element (div.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget) is overqualified, just use .bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget without element name.
```

When I remove the `div` the datepicker gets the table heading colour again.

I don't like to ignore warnings. Is the CSS correct and Visual Studio is just being a stupid robot, or do I need to look a bit closer at the CSS?

Edit: Should add, I'm running VS 2017 Community edition and .Net 4.7

Comment: Not that I am aware of. It's not something that I have installed and it doesn't appear in Nuget

Comment: No, it's not there

Comment: I have 27 items (none of which I installed myself) in the Extensions and updates

Comment: Are you running https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.CssCop-FxCopforStylesheets or https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.WebAnalyzer ?

Comment: Nope. I have neither installed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```css
.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget table tr th {
    color: black;
    background-color: white;
}
```

instead of `div.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget table th`. This way you will remove the `div` whose CSS Lint is complaining about, keeping the desired output (black text inside component).